# How to convert datetime string to ticks

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android

I have a sqlite table with a datetime column.
I updated to a new sqlite.net dll. From that moment the datevalue is stored as ticks. Now i have a mix of dates in string format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sssssss

How can I update the datecolumn with ticks or 
how can I convert the ticks back to datetimestring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update ak set ts=datetime(ts/10000000 - 62135596800, 'unixepoch')  WHERE typeof(ts)='integer'
```

did the job.